Como faço para adicionar um JScrollPane na IDE Intellij?
Estou criando um pequeno quiz para colocar em prática o que aprendi, porém ele ficou grande, preciso de um scrollpane para visualizar a parte inferior do quiz. Já pesquisei em vários sites como fazer, porém nenhum mostra do zero como realizar esse processo no intellij.
O código do quiz está assim, ele é bem simples mesmo, só tem 4 respostas pra uma pergunta. Criei utilizando o que aprendi até agora.


package MeusTestes;

import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class QuizSwingTeste extends JFrame {
  private JButton btnWon;
  private JButton btnDino;
  private JButton btnHos;
  private JButton btnCoups;
  private JPanel PanelWon;
  private JPanel PanelDin;
  private JPanel PanelHos;
  private JPanel PanelCou;
  private JPanel MainPanel;

  public QuizSwingTeste() {
    PanelWon.setVisible(false);
    PanelDin.setVisible(false);
    PanelHos.setVisible(false);
    PanelCou.setVisible(false);
    setTitle("SVT TESTE QUIZ");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setContentPane(MainPanel);
    setSize(1440, 900);
    setVisible(true);
    btnWon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PanelWon.setVisible(true);
        PanelCou.setVisible(false);
        PanelHos.setVisible(false);
        PanelDin.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
    btnDino.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PanelDin.setVisible(true);
        PanelHos.setVisible(false);
        PanelCou.setVisible(false);
        PanelWon.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
    btnHos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PanelHos.setVisible(true);
        PanelCou.setVisible(false);
        PanelWon.setVisible(false);
        PanelDin.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
    btnCoups.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        PanelCou.setVisible(true);
        PanelWon.setVisible(false);
        PanelDin.setVisible(false);
        PanelHos.setVisible(false);
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new QuizSwingTeste();
  }
}



Obs: Tenho pouco tempo como programadora, estou aprendendo aos poucos pelo youtube, porém a IDE que o professor usa é o NetBeans(que parece ser mais fácil de criar em SWING do que no intellij). Se tiverem dicas de outra coisa além do JScrollPane, também ajuda muito!
